# SEO - why did my google search rank drop?

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content

My nutrition shop websites for tampa and brandon were coming up on page one of google search results and now they have dissappeared. The 2 websites serve different markets although they are close geographically and have the same products, keywords, and layouts. Brandon, FL is considered a suburb of Tampa, FL and could be grouped into the Tampa Bay area. There's also a mirror site nutrition shop setup for orlando. Is the google search ranking drop because:

1) from a flash banner recently added on the front page

2) is the site just being re-indexed on all search engines b/c of new content?

3) is it seen as duplicate content as there are separate websites for the cities of Tampa and Brandon but with the same content?

What can be done to fix this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have so little information to go on that it's hard to say for sure but if you have three websites all with the same content then the odds are this site has been hit with a duplicate content penalty.

**UPDATE**

*From the comments below*

Those sites are definitely clones of each other so it's no surprise one is filtered out. The more differences you can make the better. If it is a template driven site change the layout as much as you can. See if you can do anything to the titles besides changing just the location name. Really, anything you can change is going to help differentiate the two. (Footer text, anchor text, meta desc tag)

Comment: @JohnConde, what other info do you need?

Comment: Is the content exactly the same? Or just similar formats but different for each location? Haver you made any changes besides adding that flash? Did that flash replace any content?

Comment: @JohnConde, thanks for your response. The splash page (index) is different but otherwise the content and format is the same for eaach location. its 2 different locations for the same store so the products/conent is all the same.

Comment: @Brian Sounds like a good case of duplicate content to me. Is there any way to differentiate those pages?

Comment: @BrianMcCarthy Those sites are definitely clones of each other so it's no surprise one is filtered out. The more differences you can make the better. If it is a template driven site change the layout as much as you can. See if you can do anything to the titles besides changing just the location name. Really, anything you can change is going to help differentiate the two. (Footer text, anchor text, meta desc tag)

Comment: @Brian, Sounds like a plan. Good luck.

Comment: @JohnConde, Thanks, I'll go ahead and edit the content, text, tags, structure, layout, and page names for orlando, brandon, and tampa sites then to add differentiation.

Comment: Any chance we can get the actual answer inserted in the answer column instead of nested away in the comments which are fairly easy to miss?

Comment: @MrG, Good suggestion. It is done.

Answer (score 3):

Several days ago, Google has made some changes to its algorithm which has been affecting a huge number of sites. Some sites have dropped unbelievably low in the SERPs, while some (like eHow) have seen a huge boost. See the attached Wall Street Journal article on the change. You may want to look into your duplicate content issue (try to make it more unique) but other than that, I recommend waiting it out a bit while Google balances its search engines. In the meantime, you can continue working on your project or work on a new one. Best of luck!

[Google Revamps to Fight Cheaters](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704150604576166390281747136.html)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate information can hurt you... but it is impossible to say more without knowing more :)

The main point you should consider is if it is your website that is going down in rank or your competitors going up. Check the ones which rank about you to see if they are more relevant or have more recent content.

Comment: How can I not vote up an answer that is just like mine? ;)

Comment: what other info do you need?